# ¿Como puedo obtener la suma de los ingresos del primero día del mes a un día anterior del actual en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Buenas tardes tengo mi siguiente consulta, quiero obtener la suma de los ingresos del primer día del mes hasta el día anterior del actual.
mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT SUM( ingreso_diario ) FROM ingresos WHERE fecha BETWEEN MONTH(fecha) AND MONTH(NOW())-1 AND id_cabanas = 1 and YEAR(fecha)= YEAR(NOW())
```

Pero como resultado solo obtengo un null.

Lo puedo hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT SUM( ingreso_diario ) FROM ingresos WHERE fecha BETWEEN  '20190501' AND  '20190509' AND  id_cabanas = 1
```

Sin embargo no me sirve pues tengo que hacer esta consulta diariamente y no se me hace factible estar cambiando la fecha.

Espero puedan ayudarme gracias.

Answer (score 1):

utiliza la funcion DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-01') para definir la fecha inicial del mes y  date_add para obtener el dia anterior a la fecha actual

ejemplo
:

```
SELECT SUM( ingreso_diario ) FROM ingresos WHERE fecha BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-01') AND date_add( CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AND id_cabanas = 1 and YEAR(fecha)= YEAR(NOW())
```